# Jquery Mobile Refresh Previous Page On Back Button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This code used to work amazing in JQM for removing previous pages from the DOM so that when you click "back" it would refresh the previous page's content.

```
$('div').live('pagehide', function(event, ui) {
    $(event.target).remove();
});
```

However, this broke in the latest JQuery update since "$().live" has been deprecated and I haven't been able to get it working using "on" or "bind" with updated parameters.

Has anyone found a working solution for this?

***UPDATE:***

I can't use "document.location" because I can't have certain pages appear in the "Back" navigation stack.

For example, if I go to a "submit page" and when it's submitted I simply issue the History.Back(); call and it takes you back to the updated "details page". I don't want them to click "Back" on the nav bar and be back on the "submit page" again, since the item cannot be submitted twice. There are reasons I don't use a dialog or popup for this but that would be too lengthy to explain.

I tried:

```
$(document).on("pagehide", "#PageId", function () {
      $(event.target).remove();
  });
```

And it doesn't work fully, it changes the URL path when I issue the History.Back(); command but the page stays on the "submit page". When I was using the "$().live" code, it worked great. Maybe "on" is not a good substitute?

Comment: I would suggest `document.location = previous_page`, but it isn't quite elegant

Comment: `.on` is the recommend substitute which should work can you post code about your issue with on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

William, you're forgetting the ***event*** parameter.

If you want to use it globally to refresh all previous pages on "back" you can use "div" instead of "#PageId". Simply put this in your javascript for your master page.

```
$(document).on("pagehide", "div[data-role=page]", function(event){
  $(event.target).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
$(document).on("pagehide", "#[pageID]", function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I updated the main thread with the results I'm seeing.